# Proof of a proposition involving universal quantifiers and a cover

Tags: elementary-set-theory, quantifiers

I started to learn topology recently. Solving some examples in a textbook, I found the solutions for some problems make use of a cover in a way that can be described as follows (if I correctly understood):

Consider the topological space $X$, the set $S$, and the family of sets $C$ such that $\forall A \in C: A\subseteq X$, $S\subseteq X$, and $S \subseteq \cup C$, that is, $C$ covers $S$. $P$ is a predicate. Then, the following proposition seems true.
$$
(\forall A \in C: (x \in A \cap S \implies P(x))) \iff (x\in S \implies P(x))
$$

But I could not figure out how to prove that. I am not familiar with logic and don't know how to correctly handle universal quantifiers.

The last question is, are $x\in S \implies P(x)$ and $\forall x \in S : P(x)$ equivalent in this case?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What would this mean in words?

Comment: @Randall It can be interpreted that if $P(x)$ is true for $x$ in every patch of $S$, it is true for all $x$ in $S$.

Comment: In $(x \in S \implies P(x))$ $x$ is an unbound variable which means this is not actually a sentence (you cannot asign a truth value to this). For the whole thing to really make sense you would need a quantor (for all or for any) or you would need to speak about a specific "x". From context I assume they mean to say $\forall x( x\in S \implies P(x))$ which is equivalent to what you have written in your last paragraph.

Comment: @Dasi Do you mean that I need to edit the proposition to this?': $\forall A \in C: \forall x\in X: (x \in A \cap S \implies P(x))) \iff \forall x\in X: (x\in S \implies P(x))$

Comment: @Hermis14 yes, that is one option. You can also bind the variable outside of the statement (saying for all x, or even just some given x that you are interested in, the two statements are equivalent). Basically any statement binding x in a sensible manner would be true which presumbably is the reason why they thought it was ok to not add a quantor. Regardless, without binding x you can't rigorously assign a truth value since it is not a logical sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=\{x\in X:P(x)\}$. Then $\forall A\in C\,\big(x\in A\cap S\to P(x)\big)$ clearly just says that $A\cap S\subseteq P$ for each $A\in C$, and $x\in S\to P(x)$ says that $S\subseteq P$. Thus, your question boils down to asking whether $\forall A\in C\,(A\cap S\subseteq P)$ is equivalent to $S\subseteq P$.

Suppose that $A\cap S\subseteq P$ for each $A\in C$, and let $x\in S$. $C$ covers $S$ so there is an $A\in C$ such that $x\in A$. Clearly $x\in A\cap S\subseteq P$, so $x\in P$, and since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $S$, we’ve shown that $S\subseteq P$.

Now suppose that $S\subseteq P$, and let $A\in C$. Then $A\cap S\subseteq S\subseteq P$, so $A\cap S\subseteq P$. Thus, $A\cap S\subseteq P$ for all $A\in C$ if and only if $S\subseteq P$.

The answer to your last question is *yes*.

Comment: The answer is very concise and clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Hermis14: You’re welcome!

Comment: So the statement 'let something be arbitrary' is used to derive a universal property?

Comment: @Hermis14: Yes. The usual way to prove that every element of a set has some property is to start with an arbitrary element of the set, meaning one about which we assume only that it belongs to the set in question, and show that it has the desired property.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\forall x \in S : P(x)$ is shorthand for $\forall x, (x \in S) \wedge P(x)$, so the second answer is "absolutely".
2. For the first, let's use that second one:
   \begin{align}
   (\forall A& \in C : (x \in A \cap S \implies P(x))) \iff (x\in S \implies P(x)) \\
   (\forall A  &: ((A \in C ) \wedge (x \in A \cap S \implies P(x)))  \iff (x\in S \implies P(x)) & \text{applying rule from above}\\
   \end{align}
   Now let's look at that last thing. Suppose $x \in S$. Then because $C$ is a cover, there's some element $A$ of $C$ such that $x \in A$. That means that $x \in A$ and $x \in S$, so $x \in A \cap S$, so $P(x)$ holds. That proves the left-to-right implication.

Now suppose that the right-hand side is known. Let $A$ be any element of $C$. Then $x \in A \cap S$ tells use $x \in S$, hence $P(x)$ (by our assumption). So that proves the right-to-left implication.